# Confidence interval for variance of two samples

Tags: r, confidence-interval

Considering I have two samples of 15 values of normal distributions with different parameters

With only one command in R could I give a confidence interval of 95% for the proportion (ratio) of the variances of the first and second sample?

How (with R) to find the previous confidence interval from the samples and its confidence level?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Do you mean a confidence interval of the ratio of variances ? Or a confidence interval for each variance ?

Comment: Yes, of the ratio

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: To clarify: In the first question you want some R and in the second question you want to back out the distributions of var(s1) and var(s2) knowing only the distribution of var(s1/s2)? The first part seems to be a programming question, but I don't think I understand the second part.

Comment: Yes it is what you said. How to find the confidence interval from the samples and its confidence level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var.test` function (stats package, so you don't need to install or load anything extra) will generate a confidence interval for the ratio of 2 variances.  Note however that this interval is very dependent on normality and so will not have reasonable coverage if the data is generated from non-normal distributions.

The `sigma.test` function in the TeachingDemos package will give a confidence interval for a variance based on a single sample (same cautions about normality apply).  There may be other functions in other packages that do the same, but TeachingDemos is the one that I am most familiar with.

If you are not willing to assume normality then things become more complex.  Bootstrapping is one option as long as the sample sizes are large enough.  A Bayesian approach based on a reasonable distribution for the data is another possible approach.